# How to "Add Web Reference" to AWS Serverless Lambda Application in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl, aws-lambda

I have created a brand new project/solution in Visual Studio 2017. I've installed the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017 and the project is a .NET Core (2.2) AWS Servless Application:

[image: project creation]

I would like to add a web reference to a WSDL url in order to generate proxy classes.

The problem is that there is no "Add Web Reference" or "Add Service Reference" options available:

[image: add service]

So I attempted to do it via "Add... > Connected Service" however once the proxy classes had been generated, none of the expected classes, constructors or methods were generated which resulted in the well know "type or namespace not found..." error.

How do I add a web reference to this project?

Comment: Have you followed all the steps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide